# Convert LINQ query to SQL query for better performance by using joins

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I want to improve my query performance. When you take a look at my previous question, you will see my question. I asked you for modifying my LINQ query. Because I need really better performance.

But I decided to look at the equality of SQL for my LINQ query. As a result, How can I convert below LINQ to SQL with taking care of performance issues? Because I need to have a better performance, that's the reason;  it is more essential than before. Someone who is willing to answer this question has to focus on

1. Better performance
2. SQL equality.

````
data.ForEach(x =>
{
    foreach (var item in x.SalesItems)
    {
        if (orderItemType.Any(y => y == item.Value))
        {
            var x = DbContext.Set<Customer>()
                            .Include(q => q.Table1)
                            .Include(q => q.Table2)
                            .FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == item.Key);
            if (x != null)
            {
                var y = DbContext.Set<Order>()
                                .Include(q => q.OrderDetail)
                                .FirstOrDefault(q => q.PNRId == x.PNRID);

                x.OrderNo = x.OrderNumber;
                x.CustomerName = x.Table1.Name + " " + x.Table1.Surname;
                x.OrderProviderName = y.OrderDetail.Id;
                x.CityCode = y.OriginCityCode + " - " + y.DestinationCityCode;
            }
        }
    }
});```
````

Comment: Why was this upvoted?

Comment: have you try .ToString() ? it will returns commands that will run on data source

Comment: its better to optimize your linq query than rewriting it into old school sql

Comment: I simplified my question for better answer. Than you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't answer directly to your question but a TIP to optimize query under SQL Server is to use the analyze "Missing Index", a good INDEX can run your query twice faster.

Take the SQL String and copy it into SQL Server Management Studio, run you query with the icon "Display Estimated Execution Plan"

[image: Icon Display Estimated Execution Plan]

After this, if you query needs to create an INDEX, you see in green something like that:
[image: Missing Index]

Click on the menu "Missing Index Details" and execute the Index with a new name undex

You'll see a better performance and it's a TIP to check everytime when you exeuctes queries in your project.